# If I can find two limits of a set relation, what effect does that have on set relationships?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I'm a bit new to set theory, so forgive me if I'm missing some formalisms here.

Let x be some finite set of actions, and y be some finite set of actions, and $\omega$ be a scalar s.t. $0 \leq \omega \leq 1$. Let there be a function $f$ that takes in a set and gives some finite scalar value.

If I have a relationship $$ f(x) = \omega f(x \cup y) + (1 - \omega)f(y)$$ then for $\omega = 0,1$ then it seems $y \subseteq x$ but if I do not have either of those two values then things become a bit less clear.

From this it seems like there's either two options: either the 0 and 1 cases are special cases, or they are just the most obvious ways of seeing that $y \subseteq x$. Since $\omega$ is bound at both ends like this, is there any kind of set property that allows me to say that $y \subseteq x$ regardless of the value of $\omega$, or are is there nothing really that I can say about y and x at intermediate values of $\omega$?